# Symfony How to create empty SELECT (ChoiceType)?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm on Symfony 2.8. I've got `Movie` entity, which has `Actor` entities (`ManyToMany`). Lately I realized I will have a problem with creating entity, when there's a lot of actors in the DB, so I want to do have ajax-autocompleter on `Actor` field. On admin side (Sonata) there was no problem with that, but on the user side I failed using PUGXAutoCompleterBundle (doesn't support `ManyToMany`).

I created API action which returns JSON with actors matching search string and I want to use select2 with it, but I have a problem on form-building phase.
I wanted to make as few changes as possible, so my previous createAction would work. Unfortunately, I can't create empty SELECT and then populate it with Select2. When I do it:

```
->add('actors', ChoiceType::class)
```

(or using `'empty_value' => true`, or with `'choices' => []'`), I get:

```
The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.
```

I assume it's because the field `actors` exists in `Movie` entity and it should be `ArrayCollection` of `Actor` entity instead of God-knows-what. I found two ugly (in my opinion) workarounds:

1. Add `query_builder`, which will always return empty set (like `WHERE false = true`). Ugh...
2. Add `'mapped' => false`, but I don't know, it it will generate the correct form data after submit.

How should I really solve this?

Comment: I would go for `'mapped' => false` and `'choices' => []` in that form field. As in fact you don't want to map it directly to your Entity.

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk: yeah, it works on the frontend, but then `$form->isValid()` returns false...

Comment: Check in profiler what fields are breaking. And what's the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I ran out of ideas, as you can see in question 35604335